# Can’t load libgd when trying to use Graphics.GD on OS X

Tags: macos, haskell, ghci

I’m trying to use `Graphics.GD`:

```
Prelude> import Graphics.GD
Prelude Graphics.GD> x <- loadPngFile "test.png"
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Loading package array-0.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.10.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package gd-3000.7.3 ... can't load .so/.DLL for: libgd.dylib (dlopen(libgd.dylib, 9): image not found)
```

The `ghci` binary comes from MacPorts, the `gd` package was installed by `cabal install gd`. There’s `libgd.dylib` in `/opt/local/lib`, installed by MacPorts. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to install it, and it works for me, and I have the same setup as you (`gd` installed via macports).

In my `~/.cabal/config` file, I have the line:

```
extra-lib-dirs:/opt/local/lib
```

If you don't have that, try reinstalling the library (`cabal install gd --reinstall`) after adding it in.

Other than that, I don't know.